# Why isn't `route` accepting target argument with CIDR format?

Tags: networking, routing

I noticed these 2 command formats give different results:

```
$ sudo route -v add -net <IP> netmask 255.255.255.255 gw <gateway>
# succeeds without outputting text

$ sudo route -v add -net <IP>/32 gw <gateway>
SIOCADDRT: Invalid argument
```

The man file for `route` clearly says CIDR format should work:

> route  [-v]  [-A  family] add [-net|-host] target [netmask Nm] [gw Gw]...
>
> [...]
>
> target: the destination network or host. You can provide IP addresses in dotted decimal or host/network names.

So what am I missing?

Note: also, the verbose option seems to be useless on this command.

Comment: The `netmask 255.255.255.255` argument means 'host destination' and overrides the `-net` switch. The `/32` does not. If you remove the `-net` switch from the second command it will probably work with the same effect. At least that's the theory -- I can't check it just now.

Comment: @mosvy Thanks! After realizing it would interpret a `/32` network as a host, I realized I could use the simpler form `sudo route add <IP> gw <gateway>`. I also played with it some more until I figured out how to add an actual network. I guess I'm only used to host notation, and I learned the hard way that in network notation, the network IP has to match the subnet mask. The feedback that `route` gives isn't too helpful. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: BTW, the newer command to set/inspect routes is `ip route ...`. While `route` still works, some kernel features will only be accessible through the `ip` command, and not the `route` command.

Comment: @dirkt oh, thanks for the tip! (I can't upvote your comment 'cuz of reputation restrictions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference should be in the arguments analysis made by the route command. In my opinion it is probably inappropriate that the result of the first command is not the error that you get in the second one, since you are trying to set a route to a host specifying that is a route to a network.

If you replace -net by -host the second command will be acepted:

`$ route -v add -host <IP>/32 gw <gateway>`

In any case I would recommend to use the ip command, with it you could add the route in these ways:

```
$ ip route add <IP>/32 via <gateway>
```

or

```
$ ip route add <IP> via <gateway>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's a point of confusion:

> You can provide IP addresses in dotted decimal or host/network names

`host/network` names seems to indicate `CIDR`, but I think they should have written **hostnames or network names** as one would find in `/etc/hosts and /etc/networks`.